# Unable to view MySQL db stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, access-control

We have many stored procedures created with SQL SECURITY DEFINER by user A
Now user B is responsible for maintaining some of the stored procedure. However user B is unable to view/update the stored procedure from workbench since the definer is set to A. Is there an way to give A and B access to the stored procedure at the same time ?

Comment: To perform this action the account must have according (ALTER ROUTINE and, maybe, CREATE ROUTINE) privileges. Check, and, if absent, grant directly. The best way is to create a role for working with routines and grant it to A and B accounts.

Comment: If both the users have `super` privileges then it can be viewed.

Answer (score -2):

use following command:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbname.* TO 'user'@'%';
```